# Why does this tkinter frame not surround both buttons

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Was playing around with python3 and tkinter.

I was trying to have a frame with two labels in the frame. I wanted to draw a border around the frame and around each of the labels.

As it is the below code shows the frame to only be around Label 1. Label 2 is below the notebook_Frame. 
How do I make sure that widgets will be inside a specific frame?

```
import tkinter as tk

def main():
    mainWinTk = tk.Tk()
    mainWinTk.title("Setup Server")
    mainWinTk.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    mainWinTk.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    mainWinTk.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

    notebook_Frame = tk.Frame(mainWinTk, highlightbackground="green", highlightthickness=3, borderwidth=2, relief='ridge').grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.W+tk.E+tk.S+tk.N)    

    tk.Label(notebook_Frame, text="Label 1", highlightbackground="red", highlightthickness=3).grid(column=0, row=0)
    tk.Label(notebook_Frame, text="Label 2", highlightbackground="red", highlightthickness=3).grid(column=0, row=1)

    mainWinTk.mainloop()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: because `notebook_Frame` is `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the reason and yea, Bryan Oakly is correct.

A call to tk.Frame() is going to return a frame. 
BUT when you do tk.Frame().grid() the return from grid is None. 
You have to do:

```
notebook_Frame = tk.Frame(mainWinTk, highlightbackground="green", highlightthickness=3, borderwidth=2, relief='ridge')
notebook_Frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.W+tk.E+tk.S+tk.N)
```

As two separate lines of code.